# strlen and non latin characters in for loop

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that sends `索索索` using post to my PHP file.

I tried strlen on it, but it gives me 24 instead of 3 (?!)...and this then breaks my for loop:

```
$in=$_POST['inn'];
$length=strlen($in)
for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
$cleanchar=$in[$i];
}
```

I want cleanchar as an individual character, like if only one character had been sent down with the POST.

How can I separate each character using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `mb_strlen` for multi-byte characters operations:

```
echo mb_strlen('索索索', 'utf-8'); // or omit second parameter or change to your encoding
```

From documentation:

> Returns the number of characters in string str having character encoding encoding. A multi-byte character is counted as 1.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not sending three characters, it is sending three sequences of 〹 (where 12345 is the character code for those symbols - I don't know what it actually is).

That's eight characters, times three symbols, makes a string length of 24.

If you were to run `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['inn']);` you would see this effect in clear light.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to fix this... I think you need to make sure the document character set is UTF-8: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in your `<head>` section.

Even then, you will get a length of `6` or maybe `9` depending on the byte length of those symbols, since that's what `strlen` measures.